# Problema al presionar boton Siguiente- no salta al siguiente TAB (paso1 al paso2)

Tags: jquery, html5

```js
//Funcion para obtener el valor del radiobutton y cambiar al tab siguiente 
         $(document).ready(function() {
              var sw ='';
              var Nombre = '';
              var Apellido ='';
              var Correo ='';
               $('#submit1').click(function(){ 
                  Nombre= $('input[name=Nombre]').val();
                  Apellido= $('input[name=Apellido]').val();
                  Correo= $('input[name=Correo]').val();
                          if(Nombre !== '' && Apellido !== '' && Correo !== ''){
                               console.log("entro al elsejdowiugsciyvewvc hdiuecbiducbiudbcoudb jducbuidc dc udvcud c uidci dkc diucduddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd j iy jdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddgyufyedge hdiuecbiducbiudbcoudbed fvfrvdffedscdsced");

                                  $('.nav-tabs a[href="#paso2"]').tab('show');


                          }else{
                              console.log('Nombre: '+Nombre);
                              console.log('Apellido: '+Apellido);
                              console.log('Correo: '+Correo);
                          } 

               });
              $('input[name=Training]').change(function(){
                  checkedSi = $( 'input[name=Training]:checked' ).val();
                    if(checkedSi === 'no')
                    {
                        $('.nav-tabs a[href="#paso2"]').tab('show');

                    }

               }); 


               $('#submit2').click(function(){
                   $('.nav-tabs a[href="#paso3"]').tab('show');                       
               });
               $('#submit3').click(function(){
                    location.href ="index.html";                      
                });  
           });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<section class="container py-4">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <center><h2>Prueba de Orientación Profesional</h2></center>
                <ul id="tabsJustified" class="nav nav-tabs">
                    <li class="nav-item"><a  data-target="#paso1" class="nav-link small text-uppercase active"><b>PASO 1 - REGISTRO</b></a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a data-target="#paso2" href="#paso2" class="nav-link small text-uppercase "><b>PASO 2 - PRUEBA</b></a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a  data-target="#paso3" href="#paso3" class="nav-link small text-uppercase"><b>PASO 3 - RESULTADOS</b></a></li>
                    <!--data-toggle="tab" ..... para ir a  los link ...  href="" -->
                </ul>
                <br>
                <div id="tabsJustifiedContent" class="tab-content">
                    <div id="paso1" class="tab-pane fade active show">
                        <form class="form-horizontal">
                        <fieldset>

                        <!-- Form Name - si la respuesta es no permitir pasar al siguiente paso -->
                        <legend><b><center>Registrar Información</center></b></legend>

                            <div class="form-group">
                              <label class="col-md-12 control-label" for="Training"><center>¿Desea suminitrar sus datos al portal web para enviarle información en el futuro?</label>
                              <div class="col-md-4"> 
                                <label class="radio-inline" for="Training-0">
                                  <input type="radio" name="Training" id="Training-0" value="si" checked="">
                                  Si
                                </label> 
                                <label class="radio-inline" for="Training-1">
                                  <input type="radio" name="Training" id="Training-1" value="no">
                                  No
                                </label>
                              </div>
                            </div></center>
                            <center>

                            <!-- Text input-->
                            <div class="form-group">
                              <!--<label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="Nombre">Nombre</label>-->  
                              <div class="col-md-4">
                              <input id="Nombre" name="Nombre" type="text" placeholder="Nombre" class="form-control input-md" required="">

                              </div>
                            </div>

                            <!-- Text input-->
                            <div class="form-group">
                              <!--<label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="Apellido">Apellido</label>-->  
                                  <div class="col-md-4">
                                  <input id="Apellido" name="Apellido" type="text" placeholder="Apellido" class="form-control input-md" required="">

                                  </div>
                            </div>

                            <!-- Text input-->
                            <div class="form-group">
                              <!--<label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="Correo">Correo</label>-->  
                                  <div class="col-md-4">
                                  <input id="Correo" name="Correo" type="email" placeholder="Correo" class="form-control input-md" required="">

                                  </div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- Button -->
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="submit"></label>
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                <button id="submit1" name="submit1" class="btn btn-primary" >SIGUIENTE</button>
                              </div>
                            </div>


                            </center>
                        </fieldset>
                        </form>                    
                        </div>

                    <div id="paso2" class="tab-pane fade">
                        <legend><b><center>Realizar Prueba</center></b></legend>

                            <div class="form-group">
                              <label class="col-md-12 control-label" for="Training"><b>1.</b>¿Frase favorita?</label>
                              <div class="col-md-4"> 
                                <label class="radio-inline" for="Training-0">
                                  <input type="radio" name="Training1" id="Training1-A" value="A">
                                  A. hola
                                </label><br> 
                                <label class="radio-inline" for="Training-1">
                                  <input type="radio" name="Training1" id="Training1-B" value="B">
                                  B. Chao
                                </label><br>
                                <label class="radio-inline" for="Training-2">
                                  <input type="radio" name="Training1" id="Training1-C" value="C">
                                  C. Adios
                                </label><br>
                                <label class="radio-inline" for="Training-3">
                                  <input type="radio" name="Training1" id="Training1-D" value="D">
                                  D. Que mas
                                </label><br>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                              <label class="col-md-12 control-label" for="Training"><b>2.</b>¿Mascota favorita?</label>
                              <div class="col-md-4"> 
                                <label class="radio-inline" for="Training-0">
                                  <input type="radio" name="Training2" id="Training2-A" value="A">
                                  A. Perro 
                                </label><br> 
                                <label class="radio-inline" for="Training-1">
                                  <input type="radio" name="Training2" id="Training2-B" value="B">
                                  B. Gato
                                </label><br>
                                <label class="radio-inline" for="Training-2">
                                  <input type="radio" name="Training2" id="Training2-C" value="C">
                                  C. Loro
                                </label><br>
                                <label class="radio-inline" for="Training-3">
                                  <input type="radio" name="Training2" id="Training2-D" value="D">
                                  D. Raton
                                </label><br>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group"><center>
                                <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="submit"></label>
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                <button id="submit2" name="submit2" class="btn btn-primary">SIGUIENTE</button>
                              </div></center>
                            </div>

                    </div>
                    <div id="paso3" class="tab-pane fade">
                         <legend><b><center>Resultados Obtenidos</center></b></legend>

                         <div class="form-group"><center>
                                <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="submit"></label>
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <button id="submit3" name="submit3" class="btn btn-primary">SALIR</button>
                              </div></center>
                         </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: Tu código funciona ? al agregar tu código al snippet con las librerias incluidas no se ven los tabs